# Making a cursor that hovers over and deletes characters

Tags: javascript, html

The cursor should initially be at the far left corner of the screen. When a value is entered, the cursor should always be placed at the right of the latest character. If the left and right arrows are pressed, the cursor should hover over either the next or previous character. When delete is pressed, the character the cursor is hovering over should be deleted.

To implement this, I am adding span elements to the DOM when the `Press to Enter Text` button is pressed; the span element's width and position are used to set the cursor's properties. When the left, right, or delete buttons are pressed, I get the appropriate child element of `screenText` and performs the appropriate operation.

I cannot get the cursor to move. Below is the code I have written. I am hoping to get tips on how to fix this program.

```js
let screen;
let cursor;
let id;
let num = 0;
let cursorPosition = 1; //used to index into `screenText`'s NodeList; initialized to one because the cursor is the first child node, and it needs to be skipped

window.onload = () =>{
    screen = document.getElementById("screen");
    fillScreen();
    blinkCursor();
    document.getElementById("textButton").addEventListener("click", addText);
    document.getElementById("leftButton").addEventListener("click",moveLeft);
    document.getElementById("rightButton").addEventListener("click", moveRight);
    document.getElementById("deleteButton").addEventListener("click", deleteText);

    cursor = document.createElement("div");
    setCursor();
    document.getElementById("screenText").appendChild(cursor);
}

fillScreen = () => {
    let context = screen.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.lineWidth = 10;
    context.fillRect(10, 10, 280, 100);
}

blinkCursor = () =>{
    clearInterval(id);
    id = setInterval(hide, 1000);
    function hide() {
        if(cursor != null)
            cursor.hidden = !cursor.hidden;
    }   
}

setCursor = () =>{
    cursor.id = "cursor";
    cursor.style.width = "20px";
    cursor.style.height = "20px";
    cursor.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    cursor.style.opacity = "0.7";
    cursor.style.position = "absolute";
}

addText = ()=>{
    //code for adding new text to the screen
    let newElem = document.createElement("span");
    newElem.id = "newText";
    newElem.style.color = "red";
    newElem.style.width = "3px";
    newElem.style.left = "1px";
    let contents = document.createTextNode(`${num++}`);
    newElem.appendChild(contents);
    document.getElementById("screenText").appendChild(newElem);

    //set cursor's properties using the new span element's position and width
    cursorPosition++;
    cursor.style.left = newElem.style.left;
    cursor.style.width = newElem.style.width;
}

moveLeft = ()=>{
    if(cursorPosition > 0)
    {
        let prev = document.getElementById("screenText").childNodes.item(cursorPosition-1);
        cursorPosition--;
        cursor.style.left = prev.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        cursor.style.width = prev.offsetWidth;
    }
}

moveRight = ()=>{
    let next = document.getElementById("screenText").childNodes.item(cursorPosition+1);
    if(next != null){
        cursorPosition++;
        cursor.style.left = next.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        cursor.style.width = next.offsetWidth;
    }
}

deleteText = ()=>{
    //Use the cursorPosition to determine which span element to delete.
    let deletedElem = document.getElementById("screenText").childNodes.item(cursorPosition);
    if(deletedElem != null){
        deletedElem.parentNode.removeChild(deletedElem);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas id = "screen" style="background-color:black; border:1px; position:absolute; top:1em; left:40em; width:26em; height:10em;"></canvas>
        <div id = "screenText" style ="position:absolute; top:7em; left: 41em;"></div>
        <button id = "textButton" style="width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:20em; left:60em;">Press to Enter Text</button>
        <button id = "leftButton" style="width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:30em; left:50em;">&#8592</button>
        <button id = "rightButton" style="width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:30em; left:70em;">&#8594</button>
        <button id = "deleteButton" style = "width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:40em; left:60em;">Press to delete character</button>
    </body>

    <script src = "script.js">
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to ask: why? Why not use the cursor that is already supported natively?

Comment: I am making a calculator that supports a delete operation, and I want users to be able to move the cursor using arrow keys on the calculator to select items to delete from the screen.

Comment: Wouldn't [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) do what you need? Or if this is only going to be *text* (that is editable), then there is `<input>` or `<textarea>`.

Comment: From my understanding, if I add `contenteditable = true` to the div element `screenText`, that lets me modify its text contents by clicking on the element with my mouse and typing values in. However, I am not sure I understand how contenteditable helps me make modifications to the screen using the buttons on the calculator only.

Comment: Isn't that a nice feature that users can use their mouse to select content and type content with their keyboard? You want to take those possibilities away and re-implement more restrictive input mechanics from the ground up?

Comment: Fine, that is fair. What if I wanted to do it this way, though? I want to model a typical hand-held calculator, and those do not come with mice or touchpads.

Comment: Is it intended that the text is first 0, then 1, then 2, ...etc? Or do you have buttons with the 10 digits?

Comment: I have buttons in my actual project; I posted this code instead because it is shorter. The idea is the same, though. My goal is to get the cursor's movements and functions working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest not re-implementing a blinking cursor, and rely on the default caret that is available in input controls.

You can still manipulate the position of that caret with [`setSelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) and the text content can be manipulated via the `value` property.

Here is how that could be done:

```js
const display = document.querySelector(".calc input");

function prevent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    display.focus();
}

function type(chr) {
    let start = display.selectionStart;
    const end = display.selectionEnd;
    const newValue = display.value.slice(0, start) + chr 
                   + display.value.slice(end);
    // Only proceed if result does not have 2 or more points
    if (newValue.split(".").length > 2) return; 
    display.value = newValue;
    start += chr.length;
    display.setSelectionRange(start, start);
}

function move(step) {
    const idx = Math.max(0, display.selectionStart + step);
    display.setSelectionRange(idx, idx);
}

function remove() {
    const start = display.selectionStart;
    let end = display.selectionEnd;
    end += start === end; // If no text is selected, delete 1 character
    display.value = display.value.slice(0, start) + display.value.slice(end);
    display.setSelectionRange(start, start);
}

// Make sure that button clicks don't grab the focus away from the input
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll("button")) {
    button.addEventListener("mousedown", prevent);
}

// Deal with buttons that should insert text
for (const digitButton of document.querySelectorAll(".digit")) {
    digitButton.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => type(e.target.textContent));
}

// Deal with arrow buttons
document.querySelector(".left").addEventListener("mousedown", () => move(-1));
document.querySelector(".right").addEventListener("mousedown", () => move(1));
// Deal with delete button
document.querySelector(".del").addEventListener("mousedown", remove);
// Don't allow interaction via keyboard (? do you really want this ?)
display.addEventListener("keydown", prevent);
display.addEventListener("paste", prevent);

display.focus();
```

```css
.calc { 
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto
}
.calc input {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}
.calc .double {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="calc">
    <input>
    <button class="left">&#8592;</button>
    <button class="del">DEL</button>
    <button class="right">&#8594;</button>
    <button class="digit">7</button>
    <button class="digit">8</button>
    <button class="digit">9</button>
    <button class="digit">4</button>
    <button class="digit">5</button>
    <button class="digit">6</button>
    <button class="digit">1</button>
    <button class="digit">2</button>
    <button class="digit">3</button>
    <button class="double digit">0</button>
    <button class="digit">.</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The Question requires "When delete is pressed, the character the cursor is hovering over should be deleted". This does "When delete is pressed, the character to the right of the cursor should be deleted" which is the appropriate behaviour. A back space button that "delete characters to the left of the cursor " as an added feature would make this functionality complete to some extent.

Comment: "hovering over" is ambiguous, since a caret usually sits *between* characters, unless it is an "underscore"-kind of caret, which selects a character (in "overwrite" mode). Anyhow, I don't think the asker will have a problem implementing a backspace-type of key, since the code is easily derived from the code I have provided. @Hamza, let me know if you need this.

Comment: @trincot Sorry for the late response, but thank you for your help. I could not understand Selection objects before, but after reviewing your code and doing some searching online, I feel more comfortable with them. This solution is exactly what I need.